# Не находит страницу, которая есть. Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Проект на Symfony, я указываю ссылку на страницу, она лежит в проекте, но сайт протестует и выдает 404 ошибку. (ссылка указана правильно)

И еще один вопрос. Как использовать .php.twig нормально, когда и пытаюсь переименовываю файл с .html.twig на php.twig ломается дизайн.

Заранее огромное спасибо

Comment: покажите свои роуты, структуру вьюшек и другой код, который относится к вашему вопросу. гадать без кода никто не станет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас путаница в роутах и роут, который, как вы уверены, должен выполнятся, относится на самом деле к роуту который обозначен выше.

Есть простой инструмент, который даст вам проверить, существует ли роут (или правильнее так, видит ли роут симфони) который вы, как вам кажется, создали и он должен работать, а именно - посмотрите https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#debugging-routes

ну или если другая версия, обратитесь к документации.

Так же обратите внимание на метод, которым вы шлете запрос. У вас, например, в роуте указан метод только `POST` , однако вы шлете запрос `GET` и недоумеваете почему роут не находится, хотя он "100 процентов есть".